# Using Laravel's CSRF Token

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-4

I have completely separated my front ui and my back-end, since I may move to another implementation for either one in the future. As such, my backend runs on Laravel from `/api/` and my front runs on AngularJS from `/index.html`.

Is there a way I can generate a `csrf` token from Laravel to use in the backend? My problem is as I said: I cannot use `csrf_token()` since the Laravel app is in a completely separate folder.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of including the csrf_token in your JSON (i suppose) response?

Comment: If you want to keep the two completely separated, then you're missing the original purpose of CSRF. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741339/do-csrf-attack-worries-apply-to-apis

Comment: Oh I see. I don't know why I didn't think of that. So basically since I do want to allow 3rd party API calls, then I am not to use CSRF at all!

Comment: That's correct - no CSRF required. **However**, you do need some sort of authentication (or other protection) to be sure that requests are coming from your AngularJS application and not from some random third-party who's figured out how to send requests to your API.

Comment: @Kryten: It's been a while now, maybe you remember this one. Do you have any suggestion for the 'other protection'? Kousha: What did you end up with?