# How to authenticate connected application with key? Django, Python

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework

I develop a web-service that through the web-API should be connected with  third-party applications via pregenerated key. 
My  solution is to use `@csrf_exempt`, but it seems to be very bad solution.
How to authenticate connected application via key?

Comment: CSRF protection is unnecessary for an API. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741339/do-csrf-attack-worries-apply-to-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [permissions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy).

You need to add this to settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'app_name.path.MyPermissionClass',
    )
}
```

And then create you permission class. As described [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions).

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class MyPermissionClass(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.META.get('HTTP_SECRET_KEY', None) == 'your key':
            return True
        else:
            return False
```